# OpenCV: Computing superpixel centroids

Tags: c++, opencv, centroid, superpixels

**Background:**

I have computed SLIC superpixels of an image using [gSLICr](https://github.com/carlren/gSLICr), which gives a "per-pixel map" of image superpixels as indices (0 to the number of superpixels-1).

This map is a pointer to an integer const array (`const int*`) containing the indices.

I now want to compute the centroids of each superpixel using OpenCV.

Coming from a Matlab background, I would do this by using `regionprops`:

```
segments = vl_slic(myImage, regionSize, regularizer);
stats = regionprops(segments, 'Centroid');
centroids = cat(1, stats.Centroid);
```

I don't know how this is done using OpenCV.

**Questions:**

(i) How do I convert a `const int*` array to a `cv::Mat`?

(ii) How do I compute the superpixel centroids from the matrix in (i)?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32844661/5008845). Should answer your first question

Comment: cv::Mat supercell = ppixelMap == spIndex; will give you a mask with all pixels of that single superpixel.

Comment: Your second qquestion: once you have the image of labels, you can use [connectedComponentsWithStats](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae57b028a2b2ca327227c2399a9d53241&gsc.tab=0) to get centroids (you use on OpenCV 3.0, right?).

Answer (score 0):

As the first questions seems to be answered, I will focus on you second question. I used the following code to compute the mean coordinates (i.e. spatial centroids) of each superpixel:

```
/** \brief Compute the mean coordinates of each superpixel (i.e. spatial centroids).
 * \param[in] labels a matrix of type CV_32SC1 holding the labels for each pixel
 * \param[out] means the spatial centroids (or means in y and x axes) of the superpixels
 */
void getMeans(const cv::Mat &labels, std::vector<cv::Vec2f> &means) {

    // Count superpixels or get highest superpixel index:
    int superpixels = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < labels.cols; ++j) {
            if (labels.at<int>(i, j) > superpixels) {
                superpixels = labels.at<int>(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    superpixels++;

    // Setup means as zero vectors.
    means.clear();
    means.resize(superpixels);
    for (int k = 0; k < superpixels; k++)
    {
        means[k] = cv::Vec2f(0, 0);
    }

    std::vector<int> counts(superpixels, 0);

    // Sum y and x coordinates for each superpixel:
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < labels.cols; ++j) {
            means[labels.at<int>(i, j)][0] += i; // for computing mean i (i.e. row or y axis)
            means[labels.at<int>(i, j)][1] += j; // for computing the mean j (i.e. column or x axis)

            counts[labels.at<int>(i, j)]++;
        }
    }

    // Obtain averages by dividing by the size (=number of pixels) of the superpixels.
    for (int k = 0; k < superpixels; ++k) {
        means[k] /= counts[k];
    }
}

// Do something with the means ...
```

If you also need the mean color, the method would require the image as an argument, but the remaining code can easily be adapted for computing the mean colors.